# How to get Facebook Graph API user_posts permission

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm using facebook JS SDK version `2.11`. For Login I've added following code

```
  FB.login(function(response) {
    // Handling Code here
  }, { scope: "user_posts" });
```

But Login Dialog doesn't have permission for `user_posts`. I also checked using `me/permissions` and `user_posts` is not there.

[image]

How can I get `access_token` to get `user_posts` on `FB.Login`. App is still in developer mode and facebook review team is also facing the same issue.

Please Help!

Comment: does the user have a role in your app? it does not look like it.

Comment: Yes, the current user you see have no role. It's my friend account. Tried using the Test Users and faced the same issue. FB Review can't verify the app because of it.

Comment: without review, only users with a role in the app can use the user_posts permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Then how to submit for review? Because their review process fails as testers don't have access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to let Facebook review your app.
[From the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review):

> **Which permissions require review?**
>
> - Review is not required to ask for the three basic permissions: public_profile, user_friends and email.
> - Review is required to ask for any other permissions when people log into your app

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get user feed at [facebook graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) explorer - this is the best testing environment.

Then try

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me/feed?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`

this is request u are in need of use.

Also try

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    // handle the response

    console.log(response.grantedScopes); // should work as well
}, {
    scope: 'publish_actions,email,user_likes,user_posts', 
    return_scopes: true
});
```

> By setting the `return_scopes` option to true in the option object when calling `FB.login()`, you will receive a list of the granted permissions in the `grantedScopes` field on the `authResponse` object.

This will definitely help you with debugging your app. If @BigJ is right, you won't do much without app reviewed. Hope my answer is helpful.